# ArcGIS Engine, How to change IMarkerSymbol size in runtime?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, c#, arcgis-engine

I'm using ArcGIS Engine 10 with C# Winforms to visualize some elements on a globe control.
All elements are of type `IMarkerElement` which have symbol of type `IMarkerSymbol`.
Now I want to add two buttons to increase/decrease element's size.
I tried this two methods with no success

1.

```
((element as IMarkerElement).Symbol as IMarkerSymbol).Size = newSize;
```

2.

```
((element as IMarkerElement).Symbol as IMarker3DPlacement).Size = newSize;
```

I noticed that I can't change `IMarkerSymbol`'s properties values after creation (like size, offset, depth, ..etc.)?
How to change this values?

Comment: you could try recreating it using the original as a template. There are a few coclasses that implement IMarkerSymbol which one are you using? Can we see a little bit more code please.

Comment: Mainly, I use ICharacterMarker3DSymbol and ISimpleMarker3DSymbol.
I hope there is a better idea than recreating all elements, because maybe there is a large number of them.

Comment: you could create a procedure to copy all the properties to a new IMarkerSymbol. Perhaps try to break it down into steps rather than casting... IMarkerElement TempElement = (element as IMarkerElement); IMarkerSymbol Temp = TempElement.Symbol; Temp.Size = newSize; then put them back together in reverse.